# GoPro on wifi and internet on Lan

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, gopro, gopro-wifi

I have here an gopro and I would like to connect to it while still being able to browse the internet, so I connect my wifi to the gopro's one ( and I can interact with it) but when I then use my usb - LAN adapter I can connect to the internet, but not to the gopro anymore

I think this sould be possible by adding routes, but I don't have any experiance on routes on windows.
Anyone got an idea on how to accomplish this?

Additional info:
If you are connnected to the gopro and go to the 10.5.5.9:8080 in your browser you can interact with the footage / live stream

Comment: Seems like a problem with the GoPro- I would need more information to determine this, however. You mentioned a USB to Ethernet Adapter... Does this imply you are using a Laptop? or are you using a Desktop?

Comment: Yea I'm working on a laptop, and I personally don't think its a problem  with the gorpo. I updated the info on original post with some more details

Comment: So if you're working on a Laptop, why would you need an adapter? Does your laptop not have a built in ethernet adapter or Wi-Fi on its own?

Comment: It only has wifi (asus zenbook) so for connecting to lan I need an external connector

Comment: Why not just connect the GoPro dirrectly to the computer via USB? This should work the same as over wi-fi.

Comment: @BenFranchuk Because it's not for transfering the video's, it's for setting up the setting :)

Comment: @Kiwi I use GoPro's Android app (named Connect) to change the camera's settings, it's easier than using a laptop. I don't think there is any option to connect the gopro to your wifi, it only can broadcast its network, at least in my model (Hero5 Session)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

https://youtu.be/ISzhlMCpk5I

You'll need a spare wireless router with DD-WRT or something similar but once setup you'll be good to go.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thanks for your contribution. Providing the link for reference is useful, but you must also [include the essential information](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) in the post. Please **edit your answer** so it contains that information. You might also like to take the [Tour] and read the [Answer] page, to better familiarise yourself with this site.